# Having trouble hiding div

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with this. I'm trying to get the .info to show when you hover over:
`.infoBanner .open`

HTML

```
<div class="infoBanner">
    <span><b>Click</b><span class="open">get info</span></span>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <span>This is more info</span> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info{
    display:none;
}

.open:hover{

    .info{
    display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't be done in the way you have your html setup. You cannot reference other selectors elesewhere in the page after a hover in css. Consider using javascript to accomplish this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this because `.info` is not a child of `.open`.

The following example would work, since `.info` is a child of `.infoBaner`

html

```
<div class="infoBanner">
         <span><b>Click</b> <span class="open">get info</span></span>
        /* removed the </div> from here */
<div class="info">
     <span>This is more info</span> 
</div>

</div>  /* and placed it here */
```

css

```
 .info{
    display:none;
 }

.infoBanner:hover .info {
     display: block;
 }
```

Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/Hqkdy/

---

**EDIT :** To only have it open if you hover over the "get info" , change the span to a div, and rearrange stuff, like this

html

```
<div class="infoBanner"> <span><b>Click</b> <div class="open">get info<div class="info">
     <span>This is more info</span> 
     </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.info {
    display:none;
}
.open:hover .info {
    display:block;
}
```

Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/Hqkdy/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have do not have access to markup and the fix needs to be done only with css try this

```
.infoBanner:hover + .info{     
    display:block;     
}
.info{
    display:none;
}
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AjLk4/